# Cooling fan stuck at low speed

Tags: laptop, fan, cooling, overheating, hp-pavilion

I have an HP Pavilion dv6135dx laptop. Recently, my computer fan wasn't working well, causing my computer to overheat multiple times. It would not increase its speed as my cpu usage went up, but would stay at the base speed that it spins at when the computer is idling. To fix this, I took apart my computer, cleaned all of the dust out of the fan, applied paste to the heatsinks, and put my computer back together. However, this had no effect, and the fan continued to spin only at its slowest speed. I tried using SpeedFan, but this also did not have any effect on the fan speed. What exactly is the problem? Is the fan faulty, or is there a problem in the BIOS or motherboard?

**EDIT:**
After consulting a professional, I've discovered that the problem is software related, so no computer parts are damaged. However, we were not able to find what the problem specifically was in the computer software, so they recommended doing a system restore, which would require me to reinstall everything. Before doing this, I want to see if I can find what the problem is, having system restore as a last resort. I was told that the problem might have been hp cool sense, but that wasn't even installed on my computer and wouldn't install when downloaded. Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be? Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you've discovered that you cannot do what you want.

Comment: If this is off topic, migraye it to where it should be. I am simply looking for am answer describing what the problem is,  being either in the motherboard, fan or software.

Comment: @Xavierjazz: Not sure how this is off-topic. The possibility of alternative solutions still exists.

Comment: I read the comment under the 2nd answer. To me he said that there were no options other than what he tried. But, I'll rescind.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps easiest option is to use a USB cooling pad.  They have one or more quiet fans and are USB powered so they are great for your desk.

Otherwise, check the BIOS if you have settings to be quiet or aggressive in lowering CPU temperature.  Example BIOS image: http://techreport.com/r.x/shuttle-sg33g5/bios-fan.jpg  If still no success, then try externally feeding the correct max voltage and/or replacing the fan.

Btw, CPUs are designed to work at rather high temperatures so what is the tempreature you are seeing and what are you using to stress.  Prime95 is one good tool for heat stress testing.

"Please note that processors can reached up to 80°C to 100°C before shutting down" : https://communities.intel.com/message/187013
I would aim to stay below 80°C although lower is better of course.

*Edit* (in response to comment)
The next question is if SpeedFan is accurate for your particular notebook. Try getting a second opinion,

```
HWMonitor -> From cpuid
RealTemp -> From techpowerup
```

Comment: When doing something cpu intensive such as gaming, the temperature goes well above 80 (I checked on speedfan).  It looks like my motherboard doesn't support manual changing of the fan speed, and the only option related to the fan in the BIOS is the "fan always on" option. It is currently set to yes, which is the default setting.

Comment: Did the different programs agree?  This is often a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to changes in the cpu fan controller it is better to check the bios because the bios is one of the software which has most control of the computer. Otherwise it may be voltage changes activity example:- overclocking   I don't know the true reason though